# Copy the Reference Number of One Column into Another column

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet in which there is a column named is Sub Category Id and a second column named Sub Category.

I have 354 Subcategory and 4500 product. For each product there is a sub category. I just copied that sub category of product in another column of same sheet and I have to copy the sub categories id against to copies one. How to do it. [Image of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWpZf.png)

Comment: This can be done with index() and match()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your data goes down to row 100 as an example. Type this into cell `J2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MATCH(I2,$B$2:$B$100,0))
```

And drag it down column J.

So, basically, you're matching the data in `I2` with the sub-categories in column `B` and finding it's index number (`MATCH(I2,$B$2:$B$100,0)`), then you're saying "Look in column A and return me the value at that specified index".

But read up on `Vlookup` and the corresponding ways to use `Index` and `Match` to return tabular data.

Hope that helps / does the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works.. Thank you.